# Create leaf node as <leaf></leaf> instead of <leaf/> using xml.etree.ElementTree in Python 3

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to build xml documents. 
I create the root node using `ET.Element('root')` and then create children recursively according to the requirements using `ET.SubElement(parent_node, 'child_name')`, and later output using `xml_minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(current_node)).toprettyxml()`.

The problem is, a node with no children is output as `<nodeName/>` but I want it to output as `<nodeName></nodeName>`. How can I do that?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/09b52471f39ba280d836b945d47719c697af0b45/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L934 - why the requirement, as both are valid xml?

Comment: It's for a course (nand2Tetris) and the professor has set the requirements.

Comment: So, the only way to prevent this is to add a whitespace to work around that...?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the serialized form is not what you want, but some other representation that is 100% equivalent? Why are you worrying about irrelevant details like this? Ah, I see the comments "the professor has set the requirements". Sorry to tell you this, but he has set them wrong. Perhaps it's to teach you a lesson for your career: every engineer has to learn how to deal with clients who state the requirements incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work around it (in a way), thanks to the comments. Set the text attribute of the childless node to whitespace or newline depending on what you want.

`>>> childlessNode = ET.SubElement(parent_node, "childless")`
`>>> childlessNode.text = ' '`

or if you don't need the reference to it

`ET.SubElement(parent_node, "childless").text = ' '`

Ref (thanks to [Caramiriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688785/caramiriel)'s comment ): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/09b52471f39ba280d836b945d47719c697af0b45/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L934